# Can't solve a problem using group by function

Tags: sql, group-by

The task: Obtain a list, in alphabetical order, of actors who've had at least 30 starring roles.

My code:

```
select name, count(ord=1)
from casting
join actor on actorid=actor.id
where ord=1 and count(ord=1) and exists ( select 1 from casting
 where count(movieid)>=30)
group by actorid,name
order by name
```

It gives me error, - invalid use of group by function.

Comment: Sample data, desired results, and an explanation of "starring role" and how that is represented would all help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Join the tables, group by actor and put the condition in the having clause.

```
select 
  a.name,
  sum(case c.ord when 1 then 1 else 0 end) starringroles
from actor a inner join casting c
on c.actorid = a.id
group by a.id, a.name
having sum(case c.ord when 1 then 1 else 0 end) >= 30
order by a.name
```

The expression `sum(case c.ord when 1 then 1 else 0 end)` will count the number of starring roles (with `ord = 1`).

Comment: FWIW, most RDBMS don't allow aliases in the `HAVING` clause.

Comment: @AaronDietz unlike Mysql, which I was thinking of.

Comment: MySQL is always the black sheep :)

Comment: Black or white, MySql would allow much simpler code, like `sum(c.ord = 1)` instead of that case statement.

Answer (score 1):

you can not use aggregation on `where` need `having`

```
select name, count(*)
from casting
join actor on actorid=actor.id
where ord=1  
and exists ( select 1 from casting
 having count(movieid)>=30)   
 group by actorid,name
 having count(movieid)>=30
 order by name
```

Comment: When I put this code into SQL it gives me all the actors that have even 1 starring role.

Comment: having count(movieid)>=30  this condition also need to add

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX(name) AS name, count(*) AS roles
from casting
join actor on actorid=actor.id
group by actorid
HAVING COUNT(*)>=30
order by name;
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value.

Answer (score 0):

This is a question in [SQLZoo](https://sqlzoo.net/wiki/More_JOIN_operations), Question # 13. The picture below explains the tables:

[image]

A little description about the database:

This database features two entities (movies and actors) in a many-to-many relation. Each entity has its own table. A third table, casting , is used to link them. The relationship is many-to-many because each film features many actors and each actor has appeared in many films.

Here is the answer I found working:

```
select A.name
from actor A
inner join casting C
on C.actorid = A.id
where  C.ord =1                    /*only the lead roles*/
group by A.id                      /*grouped by Actor ID*/
having count(C.movieid) >=15      /*at least 15 starring roles*/
order by A.name                  /* in alphabetical order*/
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT actor.name FROM actor 
JOIN casting ON actor.id=casting.actorid
WHERE casting.actorid IN (SELECT  actorid FROM casting WHERE ord =1
GROUP BY actorid
HAVING COUNT(ord) >=15)
GROUP BY name
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.